# In ethers.js, can recoverPublicKey be used for signature verification?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ecdsa, ethers.js, secp256k1

In the bitcoin wiki they describe the algorithm used to verify a signature using ECDSA with  Secp256k1. This algorithm has 3 inputs: signature, message hash and publicKey.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm

In ethers.js there is a a function with 2 inputs, hash and signature:

```
ethers.utils.recoverPublicKey( digest , signature )
```

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/signing-key/

I'm tempted to think that to verify that the signature is correct would be simply to compare the publicKey with the result of recoverPublicKey:

```
publicKey === ethers.utils.recoverPublicKey( digest , signature )
```

However, I'm hesitant to make that assertion because according to this question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/107954/does-every-private-key-have-two-public-keys-ie-y-and-negated-y-secp256k1
A private key can have several associated publickeys, thus I'm worried that for the same input recoverPublicKey might return several different valid answers, making the equality invalid.

Also, in the
**Standards for Efficient Cryptography 1 (SEC 1)** (https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf), section 4.1.6. Public Key Recovery Operation, it says:

"Potentially, several candidate public keys can be recovered from a signature. At a small cost, the
signer can generate the ECDSA signature in such a way that only one of the candidate public keys
is viable"

Answer (score 0):

It returns the public key that signed the message

> ethers.utils.recoverPublicKey( digest , signature ) ⇒ string<
> DataHexString< 65 > > Returns the uncompressed public key (i.e. the
> first byte will be 0x04) of the private key that was used to sign
> digest which gave the signature.

If you want to verify the public key then you have to fetch the public key from metamask to see if they are equal. `metamask` used to have `eth_getEncryptionPublicKey` method to get the public key but it is deprecated. I am not sure what method is used now:

```
  window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_getEncryptionPublicKey',
    params: [accounts],
    });
```

ethers has this method

```
 ethers.utils.verifyMessage( message , signature ) ⇒ string< Address >
```

> Returns the address that signed message producing signature. The
> signature may have a non-canonical v (i.e. does not need to be 27 or
> 28), in which case it will be normalized to compute the
> `recoveryParam` which will then be used to compute the address; this
> allows systems which use the v to encode additional data (such as
> EIP-155) to be used since the v parameter is still completely
> non-ambiguous.

I think this method will be easier to use